# How to load first 20 contact to recycler view and use OnScrollListener to load more to recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Please i am working on an android contact app which i need to load first 20 phone book contact to recycler view and use Onscroll listener to get the remaining contact to the recyclyer view when scrolling.

Comment: Can you show your code so we can see what you already tried?

Comment: am trying to post my code but stackflow is giving me indent error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add 20 item in Arraylist of Contact.on Scroll end add more item's and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() . This is the code to detect scroll end.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    visibleItemCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
    totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (loading) {
        if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
        }
    }
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) 
        <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        // End has been reached

        Log.i("Yaeye!", "end called");

        // Add more items into contact Arraylist and call notifyDataSetChanged()

        loading = true;
    }
}
```

});

Note : Make sure you are using LinearLayoutManager as layout manager for RecyclerView.

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: i have done this but how i will i do the for loop to get only first 20 contact from phone

Comment: ContactModel mContactmodel = new ContactModel();
                mContactmodel.setmName(names);
                mContactmodel.setmPhoneId(Integer.parseInt(id));
                mContactmodel.setmPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);          
                mContactModelList.add(mContactmodel);

Comment: @OyediranGideonEniola Then question should be how to get contact from phone book